# Incorrect values being passed

Tags: solidity, storage, logs

I am trying to copy stored values using the following internal value.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.21;

contract test{

    event LogTest(
        bytes32[5] a
    ); 

    bytes32[5]  attr;

    function attributes() internal {
        attr[0] = "0x0"; attr[1] = "0x1"; attr[2] = "0x2"; attr[3] = "0x3"; attr[4] = "0x4";
    }

    function getA() public{
        attributes();
        LogTest(attr);
    }

}
```

However, the log does not return the correct values. Instead, it returns the following:

```
"a": [
                "0x3078300000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
                "0x3078310000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
                "0x3078320000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
                "0x3078330000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
                "0x3078340000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
            ]
```

Why are the values incorrect?

Answer (score 1):

That looks right to me. You're storing strings in the array, so they're stored in their ASCII representation. You can double check that the right string was stored by converting the output back to strings, here using web3.js in my browser:

```
> web3.toAscii('0x3078300000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000')
"0x0"
> web3.toAscii('0x3078310000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000')
"0x1"
```